# Calling Win32 DLL from C++

Tags: c++, winapi, dll

I am new to the DLL world. I have been given a Win32 DLL which has a lot of functions. Need to call these DLL functions from C++

I want to call `CreateNewScanner` which creates a new scanner object and get the results in C++.
Function mentioned in the DLL is:

```
BOOL CreateNewScanner(NewScanner *newScan);
```

and `NewScanner` is a `struct`, as below,

```
// Structure NewScanner is defined in "common.h" .
typedef struct{
  BYTE host_no; // <- host_no =0
  LONG time; // <- command timeout (in seconds)
  BYTE status; // -> Host adapter status
  HANDLE obj; // -> Object handle for the scanner
}NewScanner;
```

How will I call this function? Started with C++ and here is what I managed,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  HINSTANCE hInstance;    
  if(!(hInstance=LoadLibrary("WinScanner.dll"))){
      cout << "could not load library" << endl;        
  }
  /* get pointer to the function in the dll*/
  FARPROC handle = GetProcAddress(HMODULE(hInstance), "CreateNewScanner");
  if(!handle){
    // Handle the error
    FreeLibrary(hInstance);
    return "-1";
  }else{    
    // Call the function
    //How to call here??
  }
}
```

Comment: I've edited the question just adding better text formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, `return "-1"` is no good. You are expected to return an integer. So you surely mean `return -1`.

Now to the question. Instead of declaring the function pointer as `FARPROC`, it's easier to declare it as a function pointer type.

```
typedef BOOL (*CreateNewScannerProc)(NewScanner*);
```

Then call GetProcAddress like this:

```
HMODULE hlib = LoadLibrary(...);
// LoadLibrary returns HMODULE and not HINSTANCE
// check hlib for NULL

CreateNewScannerProc CreateNewScanner = 
    (CreateNewScannerProc) GetProcAddress(hlib, "CreateNewScanner");
if (CreateNewScanner == NULL)
    // handle error

// now we can call the function
NewScanner newScan;
BOOL retval = CreateNewScanner(&newScan);
```

Having said all of that, usually a library will come with a header file (yours clearly does so you should include it) and a .lib file for load-time linking. Make sure that you pass the .lib file to your linker and you can simply do this:

```
#include "NameOfTheHeaderFileGoesHere.h"
....
NewScanner newScan;
BOOL retval = CreateNewScanner(&newScan);
```

No need to mess around with `LoadLibrary`, `GetProcAddress` and so on.

Comment: Note, I used C style casts because I'm not sure that the asker is quite ready yet for C++ style casts.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to follow the `LoadLibrary`/`GetProcAddress`/`FreeLibrary` approach, consider the following "code path" (note that if you have the DLL public header file and the corresponding .lib file, just `#include` the public DLL header, and link with the .lib file, and just use the function whose prototype is defined in the DLL header as you would do with an ordinary C function called from C++ code).

Define a `typedef` for a **pointer to the function exported from the DLL**.
Note that the *calling convention* is specified (usually, Win32 DLLs with pure-C interfaces use [`__stdcall` calling convention](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zxk0tw93%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)):

```
//
// Prototype of the DLL function, with *calling convention* specified
// (usually it's __stdcall for DLL with pure-C interface).
//
typedef BOOL (__stdcall *CreateNewScannerPtr)(NewScanner *);
```

Then you try *loading the DLL* using **`LoadLibrary`**:

```
//
// Try loading the DLL.
//
HMODULE hDll = LoadLibrary(L"WinScanner.dll"); // <--- Note the use of L"..." for Unicode
if (! hDll)
{
    .... error
}
```

Note that the file name of the DLL is a *Unicode string* (note the `L"..."` decoration). In general, you should use Unicode in modern C++/Win32 code.

Then you can try *getting the function pointer* using **`GetProcAddress`**:

```
//
// Try getting the pointer to CreateNewScanner DLL function.
//
auto pCreateNewScanner = reinterpret_cast<CreateNewScannerPtr>
(
  GetProcAddress
  (
    hDll,               // DLL handle
    "CreateNewScanner"  // Function name
  ) 
);

if (! pCreateNewScanner)
{
    .... error

    // Release the DLL
    FreeLibrary(hDll);

    // Avoid dangling references
    hDll = nullptr;
}
```

Note that since you are using C++, it's better using *C++-style casts* (like `reinterpret_cast<>` in this case), instead of old C-style casts.
Moreover, since the *type* of the function pointer is specified in `reinterpret_cast`, it's useless to repeat it at the beginning of the statement, so the new C++11's keyword `auto` can be used.

You can use the returned function pointer to call the DLL function:

```
BOOL retCode = pCreateNewScanner( .... );

// Note: some other common prefix used in this case is "pfn"
// as "pointer to function" (e.g. pfnCreateNewScanner).
```

Once you have finished using the DLL, you can *release* it, calling **`FreeLibrary`**:

```
//
// Release the DLL
//
FreeLibrary(hDll);
hDll = nullptr;
```

---

In addition, note that you can use the [**C++ RAII** pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization), and define a class with a destructor that *automatically* frees the DLL (this simplifies the code that manages the library loading/releasing parts).
e.g.

```
class RaiiDll
{
public:
    // Load the DLL.
    explicit RaiiDll(const std::wstring& filename)  // may also provide an overload 
                                                    // with (const wchar_t*)
    {
        m_hDll = ::LoadLibrary(filename.c_str());
        if (! m_hDll)
        {
            // Error
            throw std::runtime_error("Can't load the DLL - LoadLibrary() failed.");
            // .... or use some other exception...
        }
    }

    // Safely and automatically release the DLL.
    ~RaiiDll()
    {
        if (m_hDll)
        {
            ::FreeLibrary(m_hDll);
            m_hDll = nullptr;
        }
    }

    // Get DLL module handle.
    HMODULE Get() const
    {
        return m_hDll;
    }

private:
    HMODULE m_hDll;  // DLL instance handle

    //
    // Ban copy (if compiler supports new C++11 =delete, use it)
    //
private:
    RaiiDll( RaiiDll & );
    RaiiDll & operator=( RaiiDll & );
};
```

Then, in some code block, you can have:

```
{
    // Load the library (throws on error).
    RaiiDll scannerDll(L"WinScanner.dll");

    // Get DLL function pointer
    auto pCreateNewScanner = reinterpret_cast<CreateNewScannerPtr>( 
        GetProcAddress(scannerDll.Get(), "CreateNewScanner"));
    if (! pCreateNewScanner)
    {
        .... error.       
    }

    .... use the function

} // <--- DLL automatically released thanks to RaiiDll destructor!!!
```

Note how code is **simplified** thanks to *automatic* invocation of `RaiiDll` destrutor (and so of `FreeLibrary`), also in the error path case.