# How to call function in dll through its address

Tags: c++, dll

I need to call function in dll through its address. Is it possible?

This is function in dll:

```
HMODULE handle
void sethandle(HMODULE a)
{
handle=a;
}
```

Comment: Have you exported the function? [if so](http://goffconcepts.com/techarticles/calldll.html), [otherwise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2918234/calling-a-non-exported-function-in-a-dll)

Comment: Look at `GetProcAddress` documentation

Comment: Have a look here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100044/calling-win32-dll-from-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18100044/calling-win32-dll-from-c)

Comment: What have you tried?  Where did you run into trouble?  The answer is "yes you can", but I have no idea what is blocking you.

Comment: I have FARPROC address, I think it is possible to do it through a pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `GetModuleHandle` and `GetProcAddress` function, the following code:

```
LPCWSTR lpszModule = L"kernel32.dll"; // here should be your dll file path name.
HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandleW(lpszModule);
if (hModule)
{
    typedef void(*fn)(HMODULE);
    fn pF = (fn)GetProcAddress(hModule, "sethandle");
    // use it, like this: pF(a)
}
```